# Вывод игрового поля для судоку. C#

Tags: c#

У меня имеется двумерный массив, в котором хранятся различные значения. Мне необходимо реализовать вывод этих данных на форму, алгоритм должен быть примерно такой

Если значение массива равно нулю, то выводится     `NumericUpDown`, чтобы пользователь сам ввел данные, если значение массива больше нуля, выводится `Label` со значением массива.
Сам `массив`

```
int[,] EasyArray = new int[,]  {
            {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0},
            {0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
        };
```

Так генерируется `Label`

```
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Location = new Point(30,30);
    label.Size = new Size(30,30);
    label.Text = "tyt bydet vipyska iz massiva";
    Controls.Add(label);
```

Так генерируется `NumericUpDown`

```
        NumericUpDown numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
        numericUpDown.Location = new Point(x,y);
        numericUpDown.Size = new Size(30,30);
        Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
```

Я пытался реализовать это с помощью `if-else`, но что-то шло не так и если программа замечала хотя-бы одно верное значение, то она его и выводила, то есть проверка `else` не происходила.

Подскажите `алгоритм` или `готовый код` если сможете, пожалуйста!

Comment: `Я пытался реализовать` - покажите что пытались. Тут логика то вроде простая. `for(var i=0; i<width; i++) for(var j=0; j<height; j++) if (array[i, j] == 0 {numeric} else {label})`

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, после проб и ошибок, у меня получилось сделать все как я хотел. Происходит проверка по массиву, и матрица выводится ровно, то есть первая строка 9 элементов, потом переход и так 9 строк (до этого у меня выводилось все в ряд). Вот итоговый код:

```
void EasyToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int k=0;
        int l=30;
        int scoreX=0;
        int scoreY=0;
        int[,] EasyArray = new int[,] {
            {1,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,6},
            {5,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,8},
            {0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,7},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,5},
            {0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,4},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
        };
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if(EasyArray[i,j] == 0) {
                        NumericUpDown numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
                        numericUpDown.Maximum = 9;
                        numericUpDown.Location = new Point(k,l);
                        numericUpDown.Size = new Size(30,30);
                        Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
                        scoreX++;
                    k=k+30;
                } else {
                        Label label = new Label();
                        label.Location = new Point(k,l);
                        label.Size = new Size(30,30);
                        label.Text = Convert.ToString(EasyArray[i,j]);
                        Controls.Add(label);
                    scoreY++;
                    k=k+30;
                }
            }
            l=l+30;
            k=0;
        }
```

P.S. Да, код ужасный, я постараюсь его почистить позже, я плохо разобрался с классами и прочим. Надеюсь что моя тема кому-нибудь поможет. Тому кто отвечал - спасибо!